# Implementing a datatree using class lists and dicts in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i'm writing two anidated classes one is a dict the other a list?
having the trouble with the second as told,
the dict works as next,

```
class Field( dict ):        
    def __keys__(self): 
        self.k = self.keys()
        return list(self.k)

    def __setattr__( self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value
```

i'd like instead of adding as next,

```
class Store(list):
```

instead i would like to use the same high perfomance `dict()` with some indexing object
and a list sub-argument

what would be the most correct way to implement the data tree? any ideas?

Comment: Your `Field` class is just a new name for a dict as it doesn't appear to be doing anything new. No idea what you're trying to do with your `Store` class. Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean exactly by "use the same high performance dict()"?

Comment: I am so confused by your question.  What do you actually need to do?  Access some collection of objects by position and by key?  There are probably easier ways to go about that if I'm close to the mark.  If not, can you please clarify some?  I really can't conceptualize what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to posit an answer.  I *think* you want quick access to some collection of objects while being able to keep them in order.  You *might* be able to get away with something as simple as an `ordereddict`.  If not, something like this might come close.  It'll depend on your data.

```
class Container(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.data = []
    self.byid = {}

  def setData(self, listofdicts):
    for item in listofdicts:
      id = item['id'] # Something here that's meaningful.
      self.data.append(item)
      self.byid[id] = item

  def getByPos(self, idx):
    return self.data[idx]

  def getById(self, itemid):
    return self.byid[itemid]
```

Comment: well that's very meaninful to me but i'm still trying to write the object classes in a more atomic manner while i have prepared statements for each i would prefer dealing with the dict.__iter__ by myself instead of using tenths of For each time i need another data instances you know what i mean?. that looks pretty professional anyway i'll consider and write back thank you!